# When I edit a display within a view, it changes other displays too

Tags: views, nodes

I have a question about the way displays in views work:

I have a view that has 8 different displays. Each display shows content of the same content type, but with different taxonomy terms associated with each (so one display would be something like Research Topic 1, another would be Research Topic 2, and so on).

The issue is that with two of the displays, when I edit one, the other automatically takes the same changes. All other ones work fine, except two. What I'm editing is the type of research (which as I said I'm using taxonomy terms to decide what is what). When I select one research type on display X, it changes the research type in display Y to be the same.

I'm not the one who originally set up this view, so I'm not really sure what was differently, if anything, to the others to make them work fine. Any help is appreciated!

**Edit:** One additional thing I just noticed is that "FILTER CRITERIA" for the two displays that seem to be connected is not italicized, but that heading in Views for all of the other displays within this block are italicized. No idea what this means, but just adding this info in case it's helpful.

Comment: Never mind! I figured it out... Each display was still overriding the others, but I found where to change that and everything is good!

Answer (score 1):

Never mind! I figured it out... Each display was still overriding the others, but I found where to change that and everything is good!

For anyone else with the same question: 
When you click on a filter criteria, you can select options in the drop down at the top of this overlay which specifies whether you would like to apply the changes to all displays or just this page.